# c++ freopen 2 files error

Tags: c++, file-io, g++, iostream, cin

I get and error while doing 2 sequential `freopen`s , `file1` contains even number of ints

```
int x, y;
freopen("file1", "r", stdin);

while (cin >> x) {
    cin >> y;
}

freopen("file2", "r", stdin);
cin >> x; 
cout << x << endl;
```

printing data in 1st  file works fine, while in second case `x` is wrong,

if I break from first loop before reaching the end everything works fine,

what's happening with `cin` here?

Comment: freopen is a C library function, not a C++ library function.

Comment: Obviously the end-of-file condition on `stdin` sticks, and does not get cleared by `freopen`. Its manual page is silent on what it the expected behavior. You should be able to get this work by explicitly calling `clearerr()`.

Comment: cin and >> are definitievly c++ and freopen and stdin, despite belonging to the c standard library, can be used in c++

Comment: freopen returns a new `FILE *` for you to use, and you are not using it.  What do you think `freopen(3)` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause of the problem:**

The trouble comes from the mixing of C library with C++ library.

Your `freopen()` works well on `stdin`. If you'd write the same code using  `scanf()` to reads directly on stdin, it would work perfectly.  But your program doesn't read `stdin`: it extracts the input from `cin`, using the fact that [`cin` is synchronized with `stdin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/).

Unfortunately, [an error state flag](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/) such as `eof()` that is set on the `cin` stream at the end fo the first file, will remain, despite the second reopen on the underlying stdin.

**How to solve it:**

You just have to reset the state of cin with  [`cin.clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) :

```
while (cin >> x) {
     cin >> y;
 }
 cin.clear();    // <============= add this 
 freopen("file2", "r", stdin);
 cin >> x; 
 cout << x << endl;
```

**Suggestion:**

There is no need in C++ to play with stdin to read files via cin.  Write your code using an `istream`.  You can then use this code either with `cin` or on a `ifstream` :

```
void process_input(istream &is) 
{
    int x, y;
    while (is >> x) 
        cout <<x<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs1("file1"); 
    process_input (ifs1);   // or cin if you prefer
    ifstream ifs2("file2"); 
    process_input (ifs2);
}
```